# Elastic Search JS Function Return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch

Question :

Why is the variable (**resultVisitor**) returning undefined?

When i log hits inside the function **searchVisitors()**, the log is returning an array of objects?

Any Ideas?

```
  /* Get passanten telling */
  var searchVisitorParams = {
    index: 'veenendaal',
    type: 'passanten',
    size: 100,
    body: {
      fields: ["Tijdsperiode", "201_WE_Veenendaal", "940_HEMA_Veenendaal"],
      query: {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      sort: {
        Tijdsperiode: "asc"
      }
    }
  };

  function searchVisitors() {
    client.search(searchVisitorParams).then(function (body) {
      var hits = body.hits.hits;
      console.log(hits)
      return hits;
    });
  }

  var resultVisitor = searchVisitors();
  console.log(resultVisitor)
```

Comment: I guess you need to move return statement outside the anonymous function.

Comment: the 'return' is inside a callback function. Use function inside 'then' for run your code with the body response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return is inside a callback function. I would do something like this:

```
/* Get passanten telling */
var searchVisitorParams = {
  index: 'veenendaal',
  type: 'passanten',
  size: 100,
  body: {
    fields: ["Tijdsperiode", "201_WE_Veenendaal", "940_HEMA_Veenendaal"],
    query: {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    sort: {
      Tijdsperiode: "asc"
    }
  }
};

function searchVisitors(callback) {
  client.search(searchVisitorParams).then(function (body) {
    var hits = body.hits.hits;
    callback(hits);
  });
}

searchVisitors(function(hits){ // Results are inside hits variable
    console.log(hits);
    // .... Your code ... //
});
```